# python how to sum up values in list by condition

Tags: python, list

I have in python the following list:

```
[{'a':4,'b':40},{'a':6, 'b':60}, {'a':3, 'b':90}, {'a':7, 'b':95}]
```

the 'b' values are in ascending order.

Also I have a num variable, say `num=25`.

what I need is to build a list in which I sum up all the 'a's until the difference between the 'b's is at least num.

So for this example the result should be:

```
[{'a':13, 'b':50}, {'a':9, 'b':30}]
```

- 13 is 4+6+3 (sum of the first 3 'a's)
- 50 is 90-40 (the third 'b' minus the first 'b')
- 9 is 6+3 (sum of second and third 'a')
- 30 is 90-60 (the third 'b' minus the second 'b')

There are only two elements since from the third element we can't have difference of 'b's bigger than num.

I wrote this code which works but I used loop in loop and it looks more than c code than python code.

```
def get_new_data(data, time_length):
    new_data=[]
    for i in range(0,len(data)):
        sum_data = 0
        for j in range(i,len(data)):
            sum_data += data[j]['a']
            diff = data[j]['b'] - data[i]['b']
            if diff>=time_length:
                new_data.append({'a':sum_data, 'b':diff})
                break
    return new_data

data = [{'a':4,'b':40},{'a':6, 'b':60}, {'a':3, 'b':90}, {'a':7, 'b':95}] 
print (data) new_data = get_new_data(data, 25) print (new_data)
```

Is there any pythonic way to do it with as little code as possible.

Thanks!
David

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried. If we were to just hand you the code to do this it would literally be  "as little code as possible" on your part.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok sorry about that. I edited my question and added the code. the code works but I'm looking for simpler code if it's possible.
thanks.

Comment: the only change I would make is in iterating over `data`, well over a `enumerate` of `data`, instead of `range` in the first for-loop and a slice of data in the second, but that make a copy of the list so I would leave the same or use `islice`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make your code more "pythonic" is probably to use `enumerate()` instead of `rang(len(object))`. Other than that it's pretty much as pythonic as possible.